# How can I extract all classes into separate file?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, refactoring, resharper, extract

I'm using the Resharper trial and VS2008. Is it possible to extract all classes from one file into a separate file? I'm able to do this using Resharper but it only seems to work for individual classes. This is to be used on a file that was auto-generated that is 65,000 lines long.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using ReSharper 5, on the solution explorer, press Ctrl+Shift+R to invoke the Refactor menu (or alternatively right-click and locate it) and select "Move Types into Matching Files"

Comment: Ah, I see what I did wrong. I was trying to get the refactor menu to show me that option while I was in the file.

Answer (score 8):

For those that are running a newer version of Visual Studio, there is yet another solution (I realize the question mentions VS 2008). Visual Studio 2017 offers functionality similar to what Eduardo Molteni described for CodeRush. You simply click on a class name, click on the light bulb icon to the left, and select "Move type to xxxx.cs".

[image: Visual Studio 2017 move class]

Comment: Best answer for people living in 2018.

Comment: This is great for 1 file. I can't find an option for doing this in bulk for all files though.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Scott's solution, there's a **free** refactoring tool in Visual Studio Marketplace called [Move Type to File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OlegShilo.MoveTypeToFile).

It can bulk move types to their own separate files, like so:

[image]

It also provides a quick shortcut to move a type highlighted by the cursor (default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>).

Saved me a *LOT* of manual work...