# Best way too separate out classes, VS 2013

Tags: c++, project-management, visual-studio-2013

I have a really bloated C++ project (3-4 classes, functions and main all in one document) that I'm trying to organize a bit by separating out into different classes. I'm working in VS 2013.

Before I start cut and pasting into header files and .cpp files, I was wondering if anyone knows of any wizard-like functionality in VS that could automate this process for me. I tried the class wizard, but couldn't figure out a way to make it move my existing classes into a new document.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Copy/paste seems like such a clunky solution.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388469/is-there-a-working-c-refactoring-tool

Comment: "3-4 classes, functions and main all in one document" Why did you call this "really bloated"? In my book, "somewhat bloated" does not start until 15..20 classes :-)

Comment: You don't split in classes only to make code more tidy. You split in classes according to **domain**. Any tool for refactoring may help you with this. It's not copy & paste! It's...redesign!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution you are looking for is in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366027/how-can-i-extract-all-classes-into-separate-file)

I'll keep searching anyway.